# Parse Json without any property in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, json

In my desktop application i want to parse a json file to Key,Value pair List .
Where Key is unique one and Value contains another list of Key,Value Pair . The striuctre of json string is

```
  {
  "mainkey1": {
        "subkey10": [
            value1
        ],
       " subkey11":[
            value2
        ]
    },
    "mainkey2": {
        "subkey20": [
            value0
        ],
        "subkey21": [
            value1
        ]
    },
    "mainkey3": {
        "subkey30": [
            value0
        ],
        "subkey31": [
            value1
        ]
    }
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
}
```

How can i convert this kind of json string to some .Net object of key,value strings 
key=string type value List 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try deserializing to:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,List<object>>>
```

...or use something like Newtonsoft's JSON library which has a JObject class representing any sort of JSON object .

**Update**:

To use the much-easier `JavaScriptSerializer`, just do this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<object>>>>(json);
```

Comment: I tried with DataContractJsonSerializer and  search_json = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>;. But not converting as expected

Comment: I prefer JavaScriptSerializer when dealing with JSON.